Pyscho thriller/horror movie with a poison and an antidote in people's brain
This movie was released in 2013-14, while I have not seen it, I have read the plot on IMDB, and wanted to watch it.
Plot: A pyscho kidnaps a group of people and poisons them/injects them with toxins. The people are then told that the antidote has been surgically implanted in the brain and will trigger when they kill/hurt someone. They then go on a killing spree. This is the approximate story that I remember reading.
Do help me to identify this movie.

This is exactly what the imdb Watchlist is for. Even if the film's title changes, you still have a record of your desire to watch it.

If you have more details, I think you can just edit your original question. In any case, this is an improvement and I might have a match for you.

Well, I forgot to bookmark it or add it to the watch list :)

You might be after the bizarre idea at the base of Vile from 2011.

A group of friends stop to pick up a hitchhiking woman only to end up getting drugged by her with a gas. They awaken to find that vials have been implanted in the base of their skulls - which are of course instantly fatal if they are removed, a grinning professional looking woman informs them on TV screens that they have 22hrs to fill these vials with a specific amount of brain fluid, a fluid that is produced during times of extreme pain. Along with another group of unlucky test subjects and with time ticking away they decide to work together and share the burden of reaching their painful target. 

They do it by moderately torturing one another. Here's the trailer (Warning: Graphic).

This was my guess too.  Solid movie!

Great Job, Walt! I guess i forgot part of the plot and was thinking that there was a posion and antidote involved. Thanks!!
